# Retrofit: Custom ConverterFactory only for response

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have a generic response from server:

```
{
  "Error": null,
  "Data": {}
  }
}
```

So I created a custom converter factory to only get the object inside `Data`.

The main idea is to change:

- this `Call<ResponseBase<List<Item>>> getItems();`
- to `Call<List<Item>> getItems();`

**It work great with responses but when I try to send and object in the request with `@Body`the converter crashes...**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class <package>.data.entities.request.RequestLogin (parameter #1)
...     
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate RequestBody converter for class <package>.data.entities.request.RequestLogin.
        Tried:
             * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
             * <package>.data.api.ResponseConverterFactory
```

This is my custom `Converter.Factory`:

```
class ResponseConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

    // constructor

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(final Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Type wrappedType = new ParameterizedType() {
            @Override
            public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
                return new Type[] {type};
            }

            @Override
            public Type getOwnerType() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Type getRawType() {
                return ResponseBase.class; // GENERIC CLASS
            }
        };

        Converter<ResponseBody, ?> converter = factory.responseBodyConverter(wrappedType, annotations, retrofit);
        return new ResponseConverter(converter);
    }

}
```

**How can I make it use the default converter for request serializations?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OK... simple solution was to override the `requestBodyConverter`**

```
@Override
public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    return factory.requestBodyConverter(type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations, retrofit);
}
```

`factory` is a global variable (GsonConverterFactory) which is set on the constructor

Comment: Thanks. I face the same issue - when create a custom `Factory.Converter` but forget to implement such method. That's why at runtime, I get error "Unable to create @Body converter for class".